# Can shed skin be used on Cygwin (execinfo.h is missing when libgc installs)?

Tags: python, cygwin, shedskin, libgc

I wanted to try *shed skin* on *cygwin*.

Installation of *shed skin* and *libgc* seems okay, but when I tried to `make` the shed-skinned Python script, it complains:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.hpp:31:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

(full listing below)

I checked the [list of installed files on Cygwin for libgc](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Flibgc%2Flibgc-7.2d-1&grep=) and it does not include *execinfo.h*

**Does that mean that *shed skin* cannot be used on *Cygwin*?**

---

```
$ Make
g++  -O2 -march=native -Wno-deprecated  -I. -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib -g -fPIC -D__SS_BIND -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 /home/Administrator/python/shedskin/shedskinfn.cpp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/re.cpp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.cpp -lgc -lpcre  -shared -Xlinker -export-dynamic -ldl  -lpython2.7 -o shedskinfn.so
/home/Administrator/python/shedskin/shedskinfn.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 #include "builtin.hpp"
 ^
In file included from /home/Administrator/python/shedskin/shedskinfn.cpp:1:0:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.hpp:31:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/re.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /* Copyright 2005-2011 Mark Dufour and contributors; License Expat (See LICENSE) */
 ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/re.hpp:9:0,
                 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/re.cpp:3:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.hpp:31:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 /* Copyright 2005-2011 Mark Dufour and contributors; License Expat (See LICENSE) */
 ^
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.cpp:3:0:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.hpp:31:22: fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'shedskinfn.so' failed
Make: *** [shedskinfn.so] Error 1
```

### EDIT 1:

Adding the missing *execinfo.h* ([downloaded](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/histar/src/uinc/execinfo.h) from the internet) to the make's lib path does not help.

```
$ shedskin  -L `pwd`  shedskinfn.py && make
*** SHED SKIN Python-to-C++ Compiler 0.9.4 ***
Copyright 2005-2011 Mark Dufour; License GNU GPL version 3 (See LICENSE)

[analyzing types..]
********************************100%
[generating c++ code..]
[elapsed time: 2.43 seconds]
g++  -O2 -march=native -Wno-deprecated  -I. -I/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib -I/home/Administrator/python/shedskin /home/Administrator/python/shedskin/shedskinfn.cpp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/re.cpp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.cpp -lgc -lpcre  -o shedskinfn
In file included from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin.cpp:147:0:
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp: In function '__shedskin__::str* __shedskin__::do_asprintf_str(const char*, __shedskin__::str*, __shedskin__::pyobj*, __shedskin__::pyobj*)':
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:93:104: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), ((int)(((int_ *)a2)->unit)), s->unit.c_str());
                                                                                                        ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:95:75: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), s->unit.c_str());
                                                                           ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:97:46: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, s->unit.c_str());
                                              ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp: In instantiation of '__shedskin__::str* __shedskin__::do_asprintf(const char*, T, __shedskin__::pyobj*, __shedskin__::pyobj*) [with T = int]':
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:129:91:   required from here
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:70:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), ((int)(((int_ *)a2)->unit)), t);
                     ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:72:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), t);
                     ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:74:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, t);
                     ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp: In instantiation of '__shedskin__::str* __shedskin__::do_asprintf(const char*, T, __shedskin__::pyobj*, __shedskin__::pyobj*) [with T = double]':
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:136:93:   required from here
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:70:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), ((int)(((int_ *)a2)->unit)), t);
                     ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:72:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, ((int)(((int_ *)a1)->unit)), t);
                     ^
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/shedskin/lib/builtin/format.cpp:74:21: error: 'asprintf' was not declared in this scope
         x = asprintf(&d, fmt, t);
                     ^
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'shedskinfn' failed
make: *** [shedskinfn] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not aware of anyone having tried to use shedskin on Cygwin
before, mainly — I think — because there has been some (limited)
support for native Windows at some point.

Still, the issues you're having there are some known limitations of
Cygwin itself, which you might somehow mitigate by using a
compatibility layer such as [Gnulib](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execinfo_002eh.html).

That might fix the asprintf issue [as well](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/asprintf.html), though it might just be a
missing `#include` of `stdio.h` somewhere.

Anyway, I can't guarantee full support for Cygwin as I'm not using
Windows at all myself, but feel free to send an email to
shedskin-discuss@googlegroups.com — someone might want to have a
deeper look at it. If you want to contribute some fixes or
documentation, your help is very welcome [on GitHub](https://github.com/shedskin/shedskin).